# for has_and_belongs_to_many table name should be in singular or plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

for `has_many` we will use plural definitely
for `belongs_to` we will use singular
for ex:
`has_many :users`
`belongs_to: user`

But for `has_and_belongs_to_many`
`has_and_belongs_to_many :user, join_table: :blocked_contacts`
here it should be `user` or `users`

Comment: Is this a feature request for Rails or a specific question? Some context for your "question" might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`, because it is a many-to-many relationship. You can find more info [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).